# javascript prototype and new object confusion

Tags: javascript

While going over frontend master, I got little confused w/ below.
Can someone tell me if there is any difference? (in creating Object Chordate and Chordate2 and Chordate3?). HOw do they fundamentally differ??

I thought always doing newObject = new constructor is the way to build new object in javascript but this newObject.prototype = new Constructor threw me off.

```
  Animal = function(name){this.name = name};
  Animal.prototype.eats = function(){
          return this.name + " is eating"
  }

  Chordate = function(name){this.name = name;}
  Chordate.prototype = new Animal();

  Chordate2 = function(name){this.name = name;}
  Chordate2 = new Animal();

  Chordate3 = new Animal();
```

-- my own answer --

> Probably I need to watch more videos (as I assume they will say this is not recommended but I do understand how this works now. Here was my confusion and clarification.

Every function(which is another object) that gets created is pointed to it's own prototype(basically object)
Chordate which is already an object and has it's own prototype pointed to it's own object(prototype), this line(Chordate.prototype = new Animal();) is changing .prototype point to Animal prototype.
(which does look hacky, and I need to read and watch more).

So, based on that Chordate2's prototype is also it's own prototype and when you run new Animal on it, it just erases that and only Animal.prototype exists.

Same w/ (except Chordate3.prototype never existed) Chordate3.

Can someone please verify this for me?

Comment: 1. `Chordate2` and `Chordate3` are identical. 2. You are missing variable declarations (see `var` or `let` or `const`).

Comment: ok, let's get past the 2), but for Chordate? How do they differ?

Comment: `Chordate` is a constructor. `Chordate2`/`Chordate3` is an instance. Not sure how it's even possible to compare them.

Comment: `Chordate2 = new Animal()` replaces the value assigned in the immediately previous assignment. `Chordate.prototype = new Animal();` replaces the default *Chordate* prototype with an instance of *Animal* so that *Chordate* instances inherit from both *Animal* and *Chordate*.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @RobG, Chordate2 = new Animal() will also find stuff it cannot find on it's own on Animal prototype. Are you saying Chordate.prototype = new Animal() is different from this how? this is the part confusing me.  I Guess better question is, who is Chordate2.prototype in this case?

Comment: `Chordate.prototype = new Animal()` --- this should not be even done. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Classical_inheritance_with_Object.create()

Comment: @user3502374—given `Chordate2 = new Animal()` then *Chordate2* is an instance of *Animal*, not *Chordate*. You may be getting confused between the default *prototype* property of Function objects and the internal `[[Prototype]]` property of instances (see [*ECMA-262 §4.2.1*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-objects). The term "prototype" is often used to refer to both interchangeably.

Comment: Don't put an answer in the question. If you want to provide an answer, provide it as an answer.

Comment: @torazaburo I have done that.

Answer (score 1):

That's how inheritance originally works in javascript (and even with classes, the underlying mechanism is still the same).

Basically Chordate is a subclass of Animal. In other languages we'd write:

```
class Chordate extends Animal {

}
```

In javascript constructors inherits from objects. Since `Animal()` is a constructor we need to convert it to an object. So in javascript we do:

```
Chordate.prototype = new Animal(); // extend Animal
```

The `prototype` property holds a prototype or template for how the object created by a constructor should look like. In this case the object created by `Chordate` should look like an `Animal` object. When you call `new Chordate()` the prototype will be copied into `this` and will be returned as a new instance.

`Chordate2` and `Chordate3` are just instances of `Animal`. From the code and the naming of the objects they look like confused code by someone not familiar with javascript. I'd personally expect something like `chordate2 = new Chordate()`.

Comment: "So in javascript we do" --- actually we don't. In JS **WE** do `Chordate.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);` (followed by setting a constructor).

Comment: That is a seriously confusing explanation. "*Since Animal() is a constructor we need to convert it to an object*", ugh. "*When you call new Chordate() the prototype will be copied into this*" is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The first Chordate assignment "Chordate=function(name){this.name=name;} is assigning a constructor identical to that of Animal, and then the next line adds the Animal() constructor to the Chordate object.

Then Chordate2 starts off with a constructor assignment and then is overwritten as an Animal object with an undefined name attribute since no argument was passed to the constructor.

Finally Chordate3 is just an Animal object with an uninitialized name attribute as well.

Comment: "*…adds the Animal() constructor to the Chordate object.*" should be "*…assigns an instance of Animal as the Chordate.prototype object*".

Answer (score 0):

I do feel funny about responding to my own question and putting it as an answer but as @torazaburo suggested and it would be good for me to get critic as someone who actually provides an answer(up until now, I have only asked) even if it’s wrong so here it goes:

Part of the confusion came as to what below actually is

```
Object.prototype
```

I fully understand that when function is created(Animal), it points to its own prototype(which in turn points to base Object(of it’s own prototype(this is found by going up the **proto** chain).

> when Chordate function was created, it was pointing to it’s own
>   prototype. However, when Chordate.prototype = new Animal was ran, it
>   essentially overwrote it’s own prototype and pointed to Animal’s
>   prototype. Whether this is not recommended or not, I am eager to find
>   out why. I guess I was more focused on learning how this
>   Object.prototype works and what the relationship was to otherObject(in
>   this case Animal) being created.
>
> ```
> When Chordate2 is ran,
>    1)it creates a function and have it point to it’s own prototype
>    2)when you run new Animal() = Chordate2, it essentially erases Chordate2 and creates a brand new object and
>      only prototype remains is Animal.prototype. Chordate2’s relationship to that is found through __proto__
> ```

Same concept w/ (except Chordate3.prototype never existed) Chordate3.